# QLineEdit can not be selected?

Tags: qtwidgets

I have added a QlineEdit to my QMainWindow:

```
txtSYMB = new QLineEdit(this);
txtSYMB->setAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter);
txtSYMB->setFixedSize(QSize(txtBoxWd,txtBoxHt));
```

txtSYMB is not in layout, and I manually set the location later in the code. My code compiles ok. But I can not click within the textbox. Same happens for a checkBox I have

```
chkUpdateChart = new QCheckBox("Update Chart", this);
chkUpdateChart->setChecked(updateChart);
```

I can't check or uncheck the checkbox. I am new to Qt. Initially I was using layouts, and everything worked fine. This behavior showed up once I stopped using layouts. Any help please?

Answer (score 0):

Ah. Forgot to delete the setcentralWidget command. That fixes it.